# Laravel lazy eager loading ordering

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I was wondering if it's possibly to order any of the sub-models while lazy eager loading?
At the moment I have

```
Item::findOrFail($id)
     ->load('sections', 'level', 'category', 'tags', 'relatedItems');
```

I would like the tags to order by name so I was wondering if something like

```
Item::findOrFail($id)
    ->load('sections', 'level', 'category', 'tags', 'relatedItems')
    ->orderBy('tag.name');
```

would be possible.

I see other examples on here using 'with' but I can't seem to get that loading with a singular base model.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You use the same syntax as with eager load constraints,

```
$item = Item::findOrFail($id);
$item->load(array('tags' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('tag.name');
}));
```

In your example you can also use with() instead of load().  The latter is used when you want to load into an existing model, as in my example, though I suppose that is splitting hairs!

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. If I use 'load', then the Item is not found. If I use 'with', then the item is found, but not with any tags.
In the item model I have
`public function tags()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'tag_item_map');
}`
And in the Tag model I have
`public function category()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('Item', 'tag_item_map');
}`

Comment: It works for me.  You probably have something else going on.  It is hard to tell without seeing the models.